# SSD upgrade for 2013 21" iMac?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, upgrade, ssd

I have got an iMac ([EMC 2638](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_(Intel-based)#Slim_Unibody_iMac)) here, with 1TB hard drive. I have read that there is a PCIe SSD slot on those iMacs as well, originally for the fusion drive. Is it possible to upgrade my iMac with such a SSD module? I don't care if it would work as a fusion drive, or simply have it as the main drive for OS and programs.

If this is possible, where can I buy such a SSD module? [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2638+SSD+Replacement/29130) has repair instructions, but maybe I can let this be done by my local Mac shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a workaround for this. One can buy an external Thunderbolt SSD, and set up a Fusion Drive. Since Thunderbolt is extremely fast, this is a low cost, low work solution that is very suitable for desktop machines like the iMac.

There are a lot of [guides online](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2014030311173257) on how to set up the disks.

It boils down to

1. Backing up your machine using Time Machine
2. Install OS X onto a third external drive.
3. Boot from said drive.
4. Create fusion drive over external SSD and internal HD.
5. Reboot from fusion drive and re-install OS X, restore from Time Machine

Maybe one can skip the install to external HD, since newer Macs come with [Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718). This would save quite a bit of work.

Once in recovery, you can see your disks using `diskutil list`. Let's say you see the disks disk1s2 (internal HD, OS X partition) and disk2 (clean SDD).

Now you can create the Fusion Drive:

```
sudo diskutil cs create [ArbitraryName] disk2 disk1s2
sudo diskutil cs createVolume [UUID] jhfs+ [ArbitraryName] 100%
```

The output of the first command results in a UUID which you use in the second command.

After this, you should be able re-install or restore OS X onto the Fusion Drive.

I haven't tried this yet, it is merely a summary of the linked article! So be careful and make backups!

Comment: I often wish someone brought Thunderbolt thumb drives to the market.  They'd be scary fast.

Comment: That'd be a great idea. For an upgrade fusion drive, 64GB would probbly be enough. Ose could probably be manfuctured with rather rather small cases.